# mysqldump comand showing blank

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I want to export large database using command line `mysqldump` but when i use the command `mysqldump` it shows blank and nothing happen. 
[image: after login mysql]

Comment: `mysqldump` is a shell command, it's not used inside the `mysql` program.

Comment: It's waiting for you to type `;` to indicate the end of the query. Then it will give you an error message.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for quick response. You saved my time and its working perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqldump` must be run from the regular shell, not inside the `mysql` program.

Type `;` followed by <kbd>Return</kbd> to end the command you've started typing. You'll get an error because `mysqldump` is not a valid SQL query.

Type `quite` to get out of the `mysql` program and back to the normal command prompt.

Then type your `mysqldump` command line. You'll need to provide some arguments, such as the database and table names to dump.